# Combine Several Similar Variable Declarations

Tags: javascript, dry

This is a small part of a script I'm working on that generates an eBay listing with the user's photos and text. The script outputs all the code as a string for copying and pasting, as well as rendered HTML/CSS/JavaScript for a preview. For that reason, `href` and `src` attributes need to be populated dynamically, since I don't know them in advance. This snippet in particular seems to me to be too redundant. I'm not sure how to go about this other than how I have it currently.

I posted a working piece of this code and a fiddle on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55185/javascript-ebay-listing-generator), hoping to get general suggestions on my code. Since this is a specific issue, I'm posting it here.

Here are the first two statements I have which populate the `href` to the full-size image:

```
var fullSizeSrc1 = $('#slide-upload tr:first td:first a').attr('href');
    if (fullSizeSrc1) {
        fullSizeSrc1 = fullSizeSrc1;
    } else {
        fullSizeSrc1 = '';
    }

var fullSizeSrc2 = $('#slide-upload tr:nth-child(2) td:first a').attr('href');
    if (fullSizeSrc2) {
        fullSizeSrc2 = fullSizeSrc2;
    } else {
        fullSizeSrc2 = '';
    }
```

I currently have seven of those, and seven of these (these populate the `src` attribute for the thumbnails):

```
var thumbSrc1 = fullSizeSrc1;
    if (thumbSrc1) {
        thumbSrc1 = thumbSrc1.replace(/files/g, 'files/thumbnail');
    } else {
        thumbSrc1 = '';
    }
```

Here's a portion of the script that contains the HTML markup to be generated, and populates the proper attributes with the above variables:

```
'<div id="mblSlide">' + 
    '<a href="'+fullSizeSrc1+'" target="blank"><img data-name="one" alt="" src="'+fullSizeSrc1+'"></a>' + 
    '<a href="'+fullSizeSrc2+'" target="blank"><img data-name="two" alt="" src="'+fullSizeSrc2+'"></a>' + 
'</div>' +
'<div id="mblThumbs">' + 
    '<img style="border:1px solid #fff;margin:3px" data-name="one" alt="" src="'+thumbSrc1+'">' + 
    '<img style="border:1px solid #fff;margin:3px" data-name="two" alt="" src="'+thumbSrc2+'">'
 '</div>' +
```

I hope that's clear. If not, please let me know what was unclear and I'll try my best to, ah, clarify :) Thanks in advance for all the great work you guys do.

Comment: `if (fullSizeSrc1) { fullSizeSrc1 = fullSizeSrc1;` doesn't do anything. You're assigning a variable to itself. If you're doing this 7 times, use an array and a loop. Consider posting this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: In particular, it does *not* modify the link's `href` attribute.  You initialized the variable from that attribute, but if you later change the variable to something else, you're only changing the variable, not the attribute.

Comment: Why are you doing this on the client at all?

Comment: This is a script that allows the user to generate a custom eBay listing. I'm setting the variable equal to itself, or an empty string, because I don't want it to come back `undefined` when the HTML is generated if the user did not fill in that particular field. As I understand it, codereview is not for specific problems. This is fundamentally a DRY question.

Comment: Edited my question a bit. Also posted a link to my more general-purpose codereview post.

Comment: Also, an explanation with a downvote would be really great. I try hard to be relevant and concise and if I'm not, I'd like to know how I can improve. It's the whole reason I'm here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments

```
if (fullSizeSrc1) {
    fullSizeSrc1 = fullSizeSrc1;
}
```

Doesn't really do anything or change the value of `fullSizeSrc1`. You should change it to:

```
if(!(fullSizeSrc1)){
    fullSizeSrc1 = '';
}

//or if(fullSizeSrc1 === undefined)
```

To your original question about not retyping code:

I consider it a tell when you find yourself name different instances of the same type of data as var1, var2, var3, var4. Once you start counting, you should probably consider using an array.

So we have as a start:

```
var fullSizeSrc = [];
var fss = $('#slide-upload tr:first td:first a').attr('href');

if(!fss){
    fss = '';
}
fullSizeSrc.push();
```

But then we still have the problem of writing the same code 7 times right? You should look at what the difference is between each version of the same code. The first was the variable name, we solved that by using an array.

The second difference is that we indexing into list of child elements. So assuming we have 7 elements to look at `1 .. 7`. We can use a simple for loop to cut out the other code.

```
var fullSizeSrc = [];

var total = 7;
for(var i =1, i <= total; i++){
    var fss = $('#slide-upload tr:nth-child('+i+') td:first a').attr('href');

    if(!fss){
        fss = '';
    }
    fullSizeSrc.push();
}
```

But what if we didn't know the list size? Luckily that `nth-child` jquery function can return a list of all child elements

```
var fullSizeSrc = [];
var links = $('#slide-upload tr:nth-child(n) td:first a');
$(links).each(funcion(i, a){
    var link = $(a).attr('href');
    if(!link){
        link = '';
    }

    fullSizeSrc.push(link);
})
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was so close to that, and just couldn't make it work. I went with the second-to-last example in your answer, with minor modifications (`var total = $('#slide-upload tr').length;`, for instance). Also, I nixed setting the non-existent indexes to empty strings and just wrote a function that looks for empty `src` attributes and removes the parent node. Maybe I'll be able to sleep now :-0